# Contact Builder in marketing cloud is missing

Tags: marketing-cloud

The contact Builder is missing suddenly I have an administrator profile and was able to see it before but suddenly not able to see it.

Please let me know what permission or what needs to be done to see the Contact Builder in exact target marketing cloud.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing that's changed is the May release is now live. You can view the release notes [here](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/resources/release_notes/may_2016_release/#beta).

You should be looking at the `Data & Analytics menu` and you should see something like

[image]

If that's not the case, you should raise a support case.